# Where should one look for logs when debugging a new problem?

Tags: debugging, logs

When a bug or problem arises, one must often seek out the corresponding error-messages or error-logs. Since Civi runs on a large stack, there can be several layers to check, e.g.

- The browser's Javascript console
- The Civi application log
- The PHP error log
- The httpd log

The answers vary a bit (depending on CMS, browser, server platform, etc), but there's also a fairly limited range -- in general usage, there are only a handful of common CMSs (Drupal/Joomla/WordPress), common browsers (Firefox/Chrome/Safari/IE), and common server platforms. For web-designers and moderately-technical site builders, it would help to have a cheatsheet with common places to look.

I found a couple pages about debugging strategies in Civi. The [bug-reporting](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting) page discusses the high-level business process of using forums and issue trackers. The [Debugging for developers](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers) page is very developer-centric (eg adding new log statements to the source-code; installing+configuring xdebug). However, I could not find a concrete list of places or instructions for checking logs.

Comment: Aha a trick question, where the only correct answer involves someone else creating some new documentation! Very clever, Tim. I'd love to see such a thing as well, i.e. a "how to find more if something is going wrong" for non-developers.

Comment: Drats! You saw through my scheme!

Comment: See also http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/civicrm-is-showing-a-blank-page-white-screen-how-do-i-debug-this/6400

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the type of error you are getting. If something is wrong with the display or some ajax functionality isn't working I check the JavaScript console. If there is an actual error message I check the php log and then turn on display back-trace to get a better view of where the problem is occurring.