# I have installed and unzipped Civi in WordPress plugins directory, CiviCRM installer page is blank?

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have installed and unzipped Civi in wordpress/wp-content/plugins directory via these directions:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5.

When I get to step 5, however, and visit the Civi Install page on settings - CiviCRM installer, the page content is blank.

Also, there is nothing in the error logs.

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Thank you!

AK

Comment: Did you log in CiviCRM error logs AND apache / nginx logs? Also - is you php error_reporting on? if so php errors will show up - although when you go live it should probably be off

Comment: Check permissions on unzipped files.

Comment: Please see [this answer to a similar question for Joomla](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/joomla-backend-admin-civi-white-page-after-installation/2812#2812), it applies identically to WordPress installs, covers a lot of the basics of "how do I debug", and points to further reading if the advice there doesn't provide you with an answer straight away. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I think most folks asking this question don't know what they're looking for.  If you have a moment, could you please edit this to explain what to look for?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, login to your WordPress site with Administrator level permissions.

In Admin, Go to plugins section and activate the CiviCRM plug-in.
After that, open a new browser window and enter and run the following URL "http:///wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install

You should then see the Installer screen where you can follow the given instructions.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I would check what version of PHP your server is running. CiviCRM recommends PHP 5.4+.
More here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements

Comment: PHP: 5.4.40, from what I can tell I should be good on that front.