# civicrm dashboard won't load

Tags: dashboard

civicrm 4.6.8/joomla 3.4.1/php 5.6.11

moved civi to new server

everything seems ok EXCEPT the civi home page which hangs trying to display the dashboard

here's the log dump from the error

http://pastebin.com/JY0xM3A6

so civi is losing connection to mysql ???

if i enter civi via another url
(eg  http://..../administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/manage&reset=1)

all is well.  and i can navigate to every other civi screen and function without a problem.  in place editing works fine.

but obviously hanging on the home page is a real problem for users.

my php environments are very similar (new host is slightly newer version).

http://yea.org/tmp/ChangeDetection%20-%20Comparison%20of_%20phpinfo().html

yellow stuff is new host

tried trunc'ing dashboard_contacts

php error_reporting is the same as on the old site

any ideas to try?

Comment: First things first, please see this related question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render

Comment: looked through all that.  my settings file and base url match.  and ajax is working on the inline edits throughout civi so i dont think there's any problem with the site communicating with itself.  no proxy installed.

Comment: There's also [dashlet refresh can crash server](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16035) and [user without contact record](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3477/149). As well as your CiviCRM log, check your **MySQL error log** and **PHP/webserver error logs** for indications of why the MySQL connection dropped. [Also some some general advice on debugging WSoD/PHP errors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/joomla-backend-admin-civi-white-page-after-installation/2812#2812). (There are three links to read in this comment.)

Comment: Also [Moving an Existing Installation to a new server or location](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location), which is an *insanely* long piece of documentation with many tricks and traps. This is probably the first step - only just realised you mention relocating at the start of your question.

Comment: i complied with all those recommendations.

and i'll point again that the rest of civi seems to rolling right along -- just that dashboard that crashes and burns.  to me that seems like a pretty big clue to localizing the error but hey im just a  user now -- not writing civi code  (at least not yet) :-)

Comment: The answer should be in your error logs - either for MySQL or PHP. Do you have access to them?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this kind of thing is usually caused by something (a hosting setting?) trying to use a www.- site URL and CiviCRM using a non-www. site URL in the civicrm.settings.php files, or the othe way around.

Comment: my .htaccess rewrites any attempts to go to www.sitename.org to sitename.org.  and civi is configured consistently to use sitename.org. this should not really be an issue.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?