# CiviCRM Dashboard Hangs for 2 minutes

Tags: base-page

I have installed a site under wordpress with Civicrm.
Everytime i log on the site, i have to wait 2 minutes befor i can have access to civicrm.
After that, no problem to navigate between the pages.
I looked for past messages:
[CiviCRM Dashboard Hangs for 5+ minutes](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12886/civicrm-dashboard-hangs-for-5-minutes)

[CiviCRM Dashboard Hangs for 5+ minutes part 2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14343/civicrm-dashboard-hangs-for-5-minutes-part-2)

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/

[first CiviCRM request of each session takes 4 minutes, afterwards works fine](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22068/first-civicrm-request-of-each-session-takes-4-minutes-afterwards-works-fine)

Here is the results :
no errors in wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/

I changed the value to 1 to const CHECK_TIMER in plugings/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php to see if civicrm check were responsible : no change after that, i can switch between pages et menus with no delay   -> NOK

I replaced th ip value by the site address in civicrm.settings.php ->NOK

I changed in /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1  address_of_my-site  ->NOK

I used the suppresses civicrm checks extension in wordpress  ->NOK

My DNS is ok in /etc/resolv.conf

I don't have any other idea, a clue would be much appreciate :)

Comment: I forgot to tell that everytime i click on civicrm (https://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM), i have to wait for 2 minutes.
If i click on settings and for example settings/ressources urls, i can find the menu and everything is ok after that, until i click again on CiviCRM

Comment: What extensions are in use?

Comment: in worpress, none. In civicrm, CKeditor4, contribution cancel actions and FlexMailer (i think these extensions are activated by default). For the Components, none are activated.

Answer (score 1):

When you visit CiviCRM's admin page, by default it loads a couple of dashlets that pull content from civicrm.org

If it's you first time in a while visiting that page, it's going to pull it fresh, but if you then go back in the same session, it'll show you a cached version.

Your description tells me either that your server's connection to civicrm.org is extremely slow (and/or your server itself is underprovisioned), or (more likely) it's actually failing to connect to civicrm.org for reasons like a firewall or network topology.

Conclusion: if you do eventually see those dashlets, it's likely to be a network or server type issue. If you don't, then it's probably a firewall or (intentional) network setup that prevents your install from connecting to civicrm.org.

Note: you can test this by removing all the dashlets from your admin page and see what impact it has.

Comment: thanks for the tips. Unfortunately, the dashlets were available and not used. If i use them,  civicrm ressources and news are blanked, so it must be a network restriction as you said.
I didn't see how to delete these daslets.
 I tried to use a wordpress plugin redirection, but it seem not working with php pages.

Comment: A network issue like this not just a hassle here, but likely will impact other things (e.g. WP's ability to update itself or even tell you when it needs an update). You should get the network/firewall issue fixed. If your site is on a public ip and is intended to be publicly accessible, then it's likely a firewall that needs to allow outgoing port 80/443 connections.

Comment: sorry for the delay (holidays). My server is behind a university firewall and we use proxy to access the internet. Ports 80 and 443 are open. I use a debian with wordpress. With proxy I can update debian, and worpress update too. Why civicrm doesn't have a file to indicate a proxy ? All others virtual servers i take care have this option. Another thing : i realized today that even if i connect with an admin user in wordpress, i don't have the rights to manage dashboard on the civicrm homepage (this is why i said i have 3 ressources available/enabled, no other choice).

Comment: Ah, so the actual mechanism at work to load the dashlets is a bit complicated. Here's the most useful post I've seen: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/ssl-enabled-civicrm-with-forever-loading-dashlets

Comment: In other words, there seems to be a few ways to fail. If you have a cli to your server, you could try accessing yourself via curl, that might expose an issue, for example.