# Internal Server Error

Tags: drupal, error

I've been working with CiviCRM for almost a year now. One problem we have is we frequently see the Internal Server Error 500 white screen of death. In particular, we cannot use the contact de-dupe tools. When we try to use them, the page runs for about a minute, then we get the error 500.
Does anybody know how to diagnose what is actually failing when the error 500 happens?
We are running CiviCRM 4.6.9 within Drupal 7 on Windows Server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, look for these logs:

- CiviCRM's log (`sites/*/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/`)
- HTTPD error log
- PHP error log

Unfortunately, the locations of these differ by environment, and I don't know an answer for Windows Server.

Posted a similar (but broader) question: [Where should one look for logs when debugging a new problem?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/376/where-should-one-look-for-logs-when-debugging-a-new-problem)