# Paypal ipn issues after upgrade to 4.6.15.

Tags: paypal, ipn

Paypal ipn is failing with 500 after upgrading to 4.6.15 from 4.6.10

The notification url looks correct but isn't working
https://www.mysite.com/civicrm/extern/ipn.php?reset=1&contactID=83&contributionID=80&module=contribute

I am using Drupal 7 with Pantheon. I already have implemented this patch
https://www.drupal.org/node/2177647

I'm not sure how to further debug this. The extern/ipn.php file hasn't changed from 4.6.10 to 4.6.15. Where else can I look.

Any tips on debugging would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Why is IPN failing on Pantheon?**

Check out [CRM-17212: IPN and other scripts break on Pantheon due to session handler](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17212) although it does look like you have a similar patch in effect. Compare your changes with those merged into the 4.7 branch, or consider trying 4.7.

**How do I debug on Pantheon?**

On Pantheon hosting, you can inspect your application's error logs in:

```
logs/php-error.log
```

For additional tips on debugging PHP errors, see also:

- [Where should one look for logs when debugging a new problem?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/376/where-should-one-look-for-logs-when-debugging-a-new-problem) and
- [How do I debug CiviCRM when I hit a blank page / white screen / fatal error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6399/how-do-i-debug-civicrm-when-i-hit-a-blank-page-white-screen-fatal-error)

Pantheon specific docs on logfiles are:

- https://pantheon.io/docs/debug-log-files/
- https://pantheon.io/docs/php-errors/