# Has anyone experienced member receipts not being sent out all the time when sending from the back end of a membership record?

Tags: civimember

We are using 4.7.11 and Drupal 7

Our client is having issues where they try to send out a member receipt/confirmation from the backend of a member record.  Sometimes the receipt gets sent but other times it does not.  They recently upgraded their version of CiviCRM and it was not happening in the previous version.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and if so what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you'll find the answers you need in the CiviCRM debug log. Also check your server's mail logs to confirm what's actually happening, so you can identify whether there's an issue with the email being *generated* or *delivered*.

- [Where should one look for logs when debugging a new problem?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/376/where-should-one-look-for-logs-when-debugging-a-new-problem)
- CiviCRM wiki: [Debugging for developers](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers)

It's possibly an issue with a customised message template not being valid Smarty - we've seen this affect Smarty templates before, which use `{` / `}` to denote template markup and are not validated when edited through CiviCRM.

As a result it's very easy for admin users to unknowingly include CSS or JS in the message templates, not knowing the template will fail when executed in context of a system email.