# how do I find error log to see what is causing the error

Tags: contacts, search

I am not the technical person - merely a user so I am very unfamiliar with this tool.  I am trying to find the reason for the error I receive when trying to search the contacts for all individual contacts.  The error I receive is: Sorry. A non-recoverable error has occurred.  DB Error: unknown error.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/376/where-should-one-look-for-logs-when-debugging-a-new-problem this might help you.

Comment: And this post: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/6399/127

Answer (score 4):

The links in the comments are helpful, but don't actually give the correct answer for the log in question.

There's two ways to see the logs for your error:

- Check the ConfigAndLog directory.  You can find it here: [Where are the "ConfigAndLog" and "templates_c" directories?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15931/where-is-the-configandlog-directory)
- You can also see the error on-screen:  Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**, and select both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace".  Then repeat whatever issue led to the error!  Make sure to turn this off when you're done - leaving it turned on can leak information to a potential hacker, which is why they're not on by default.
- Install the [Log Viewer extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer) from your **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.  This will add a new entry under **Administer menu » Administration Console**.