# 403 error accessing PDF view of report

Tags: permissions, pdf, logs

We're running CiviCRM 4.7.13 on Drupal 7.51 on a shared server.

I am the administrator for our site and AFAICT, I have admin privileges for everything.  However, whenever anyone, myself included, opens a report (eg Membership Detail report), we can view the results on screen, page through them etc., but we can't print the report, print to PDF or export as CSV, all we get in each case is the 403 "Forbidden" error.

My main problem trying to work out the cause of this problem is finding some sort of error message.  Thanks to [how do I find error log to see what is causing the error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15915/how-do-i-find-error-log-to-see-what-is-causing-the-error) and pages linked from that question I've been able to locate our PHP log file and our CiviCRM log file but neither shows any entries that are obviously related to this problem.

I believe this is a symptom of some broader issues we have with the Organic Groups module on our site so I am mainly looking for tips on increasing the usefulness of existing logs (or any other logs I should be looking for).  Other questions on those topics haven't helped me so far.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you talk to your hosting provider.  It is possible that they may be incorrectly marking this as suspicious activity and hence giving you a 403 error.  Hosting companies are continuously updating their server monitoring rules that seek to prevent malicious activity. Occasionally this creates false positives.  If this is the case they should be able to whitelist your site.

Comment: Thanks William.  After posting my question, another issue we had been having with the site sent me to the hosting provider and we then went through a multi-step process where the provider's support person whitelisted a firewall rule and I tested to see if the problem resolved.  Eventually after about 7 or 8 iterations, the problem went away.  So, it seems that this problem was caused by changes the hosting provider had made to improve security.  Cudos to our hoster VentraIP for their work with me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Oh, and the lack of anything in the logs accessible to me turned out to be a clue that this problem due to something outside Drupal/CiviCRM.