# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: database

I am facing DataTables warning:

> table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

When I tried to load up the CiviCRM from Joomla and when I tried to open the data inside the civiCRM it gives me an error

> An error has occurred. 0 `<div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en"> <style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css); </style> <div class="messages status no-popup"> <i class="crm-i fa-exclamation-triangle crm-i-red"></i> <span class="status-fatal">`
>
> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill
> your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator
> or service provider with more details about what action you were
> performing when this occurred.
>
> `</span> <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">`
>
> One of parameters (value: sort_name) is not of the
> type MysqlColumnNameOrAlias
>
> `</div> <p><a href="/administrator/" title="Main Menu">`
>
> Return to home page.
>
> `</a></p> </div> </div> <script language="JavaScript"> function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } } </script>`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please check your [CiviCRM errors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/15934/12) and edit your question to paste in what you find? Note that the "Debugging and Error Handling" approach won't work here, you either need to check the logs or install Log Viewer.  If you have questions about following the linked instructions, ask for help on https://civicrm.stackexchange.com.